# iid Exponential Distribution, work out $P(X<Y+Z)$

Tags: probability

Let $X,Y,Z$ be iid random variables with $Exp(a)$ distribution for $a>0$. How can we find $P(X<Y+Z)$?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Maths.SE. Thank you for your question! It is good practice on this site to add a bit of information on the context your question came up in, and to share your own work on it. It's also fine if you state that you're completely lost -- the information is helpful for answerers to gauge their answer on. For more information on asking a good question on this site, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/43351).

Answer (score 4):

Let $W=Y+Z$. The density of $W$ is the convolution of the pdf of $Y\sim\operatorname{Exp}(a)$ and the pdf of $Z\sim\operatorname{Exp}(a)$, i.e. 
$$
f_W(w)=\begin{cases} a^2w\operatorname{e}^{-aw} & \text{for }w\ge 0\\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
So you have to find
$$
\Bbb{P}(X\le Y+Z)=\Bbb{P}(X\le W)=\int_0^{+\infty}\Bbb{P}(X\le w)f_W(w)\operatorname{d}w=\int_0^{+\infty}F_X(w)f_W(w)\operatorname{d}w.
$$
You'll find
$$
\Bbb{P}(X\le Y+Z)=\int_0^{+\infty} \left (1-\operatorname{e}^{-aw}\right)a^2w\operatorname{e}^{-aw}\operatorname{d}w=\frac{3}{4}.
$$

Comment: There's an error somewhere ... if $a>4$ the probability exceeds $1$.

Comment: corrected now. thanks.